# Alternatives to making changes to /etc/ld.conf.so.d as root?

Tags: linux, unix

I am writing an application in fortran that requires a specific, non-standard library. I have downloaded the source of the library and compiled it to get the .so file in a subdirectory of $HOME. Now to make this library available to applications I write, I came across a popular method: adding file(s) to /etc/ld.conf.so.d containing the path to the library. Followed by ldconfig.

The problem is that I do not have root access. Even if I had, I am not sure it is necessary (or safe) to make an administrative change for one library that only I need to use. Is there a method to do this that does not require root access?

Comment: I like the reference to "2001" :)  If you're a fan, you might also enjoy the Kubrick references in "Prometheus".  And if you've seen "Prometheus", you'll enjoy this link: http://www.omg-ponies.com/

Answer (score 7):

The best approach is to add `-Wl,-rpath=/home/you/yourlibrary/dir` when you link the applications which use that library.

This is better than setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in that it only affects the applications you build (and only the ones that use the library), rather than every application you run.

Comment: This is the best way to go, especially since source code is available. See this site (http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely the best alternative is to set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

- [How to correctly use LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://www.wiredrevolution.com/system-administration/how-to-correctly-use-ld_library_path)
- [Shared libraries Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)
- [man ld.so](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/ld.so/)
- use "[ldd](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man1/ldd.1.html)" to see which libraries are being used

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is almost always *not* the best alternative.